# How to organize a chunk of text in different lines without using print?

Tags: r

So I have this function to create a piece of text and I want each of the "paste" functions inside the main one to be in different lines, I tried using sep="\n" and collapse="\n" but it's not working

```
summary_library=function(taxon19){
  paste(paste("Number of specimens with A grade:",as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="A")))," ","Percentage:",signif((as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="A"))*100)/length(taxon19$species)),digits=3),"%"),
  paste("Number of specimens with B grade:",as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="B")))," ","Percentage:",signif((as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="B"))*100)/length(taxon19$species)),digits=3),"%"),
  paste("Number of specimens with C grade:",as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="C")))," ","Percentage:",signif((as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="C"))*100)/length(taxon19$species)),digits=3),"%"),
  paste("Number of specimens with D grade:",as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="D")))," ","Percentage:",signif((as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="D"))*100)/length(taxon19$species)),digits=3),"%"),
  paste("Number of specimens with E grade:",as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="E")))," ","Percentage:",signif((as.numeric(length(which(taxon19$grade=="E"))*100)/length(taxon19$species)),digits=3),"%"),
  paste("Number of different species:",length(unique(taxon19$species))),
  paste("Number of different BIN numbers:",length(unique(taxon19$BIN))),
  paste("Number of different collectors:",length(unique(taxon19$collectors))),
  paste("Number of different countries:",length(unique(taxon19$country)),collapse="\n"),
  paste("Total Number of specimens in reference library:",length(taxon19$species),collapse="\n"),sep="\t")
}
```

Currently the text appears like this:

```
Number of specimens with A grade: 166 Percentage: 60.8 %    Number of specimens with B grade: 3 Percentage: 1.1 %   Number of specimens with C grade: 85 Percentage: 31.1 % Number of specimens with D grade: 19 Percentage: 6.96 % Number of specimens with E grade: 0 Percentage: 0 % Number of different species: 24 Number of different BIN numbers: 28 Number of different collectors: 51  Number of different countries: 22   Total Number of specimens in reference library: 273
```

I wanted something like this:

```
Number of specimens with A grade: 166 Percentage: 60.8 %    
Number of specimens with B grade: 3 Percentage: 1.1 %   
Number of specimens with C grade: 85 Percentage: 31.1 % 
Number of specimens with D grade: 19 Percentage: 6.96 % 
Number of specimens with E grade: 0 Percentage: 0 % 
Number of different species: 24 
Number of different BIN numbers: 28 
Number of different collectors: 51  
Number of different countries: 22   
Total Number of specimens in reference library: 273
```

Thanks for any response in advance

Comment: Are you doing anything with the text ? If you just want to display the text try using `print` instead of `paste`.

Comment: I'm using the function in a shiny web app and from what I've been told I'm advised to not use print in this particular case

Comment: I don't think you'll directly not be able to use `paste` to print on new line. You can use `cat` after using `sep = "\n"` in outer `paste`. For example, see `cat(paste(paste("Number of specimens with A grade:",10),
paste("Number of specimens with B grade:",10),
paste("Number of specimens with C grade:",20), sep = "\n"))`

Comment: Why you have been told to not use print?

Comment: the thing is that cat also prints... a college told me it makes it difficult to format the text in the shiny app if I use print

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cat (with \n for new line) command instead of print as follows

```
summary_library2=function(){
    paste(paste("Number of specimens with A grade:"," ","Percentage:","%"),
          paste("Total Number of specimens in reference library:",collapse="\n"),sep="\t")
}

summary_library3=function(){
    paste(cat("Number of specimens with A grade:"," ","Percentage:","%"),
          cat("\nTotal Number of specimens in reference library:",collapse="\n"),sep="\t")
}

print(summary_library2())
print ("--------------------")
print(summary_library3())
```

The output can be compared as follows

[image: Output]